# Are questions about the Samsung Gear S3 smartwatch on topic here?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I've been trying to find an appropriate StackExchange site to come to, to ask questions about using, configuring, and troubleshooting my Samsung Gear S3 smartwatch. This seems to be the closest fit so far. Would it be on-topic here?

Comment: Note: The Gear S3 is a Tizen-based smartwatch. So, it's not on-topic for [Android.SE].

Comment: Tizen has been voted off-topic on more sites than just Android.  The watch seems borderline for IoT.SE but this is probably the closest fit available.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say yes. We already have some questions about [smart watches](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-watches). It might be dependent on the specific question how welcome it is but I consider wearables and smart watches part of the Internet of Things.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, no.

A smart watch is just a very compact computer - somewhere between a mini-PDA and (for those with their own mobile radio) a mini-smartphone.

As such, it would only be on topic here when used for an IoT purpose.

The simplest was to tell if a question would be on topic would be to consider **if it would be on topic if you replaced "smartwatch" with "phone" or "laptop"**

On Topic:

- Using a smart watch to control the lights in your home.
- Using a smart watch as a bicycle computer

Off Topic:

- Transferring calendar events from phone to smart watch.
- Backing up personal data from a smart watch

Getting sidetracked into general smart watch user support would be as far from the mission of this site as getting sidetracked into everyday smart phone, laptop, or TV support would be.